# C++ async function call without waiting and return - how to?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

How to generate async function calls like in JS (you fire it and it goes to work independently)?

```
while(true)
{
 if(s == "123")
  //fire an async function to do some work and continue the cycle immediately
}
```

I do not need to wait, just start an average function with params to run when the system has time, but the cycle must not to be paused and waiting. It will run on Linux.

EDIT:
If I use it like this:

```
while(true)
{
     if(s == "123")
      std::future<std::string> resultFromDB = std::async(std::launch::async, fetchDataFromDB, "Data");
}
```

, will it be a problem, that resultFromDB gets another async assigned in each cycle run?

Comment: You won't get "like in JS" in an easy way with C++. That would require setting up an event loop, which C++ does not support out of the box. As an alternative you can use threads or [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with `std::launch::async`. Note that the actual choice heavily depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not if you don't care about the result. Note that running `std::async` in an infinite loop will spawn a thread each time. Perhaps using a threadpool is a better idea.

Comment: Sounds like event driven design. Not out of the box in C++. There are a lot of libraries whichhandle registration on and emitting signals an conditions. There are also some kind of "automated vars" where you can assign terms on conditions while these therms itself are generating signals on specified values...

Comment: If you just want to fire and forget, `std::thread thr(fetchDataFromDB, "Data"); thr.detach();` will do it. But after that you have no control over the thread. This is probably a design problem, not a coding issue.